# Excel - Increment a number based on values from two other columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 columns one is a period and another is a cycle.   I need to create a 3rd column where I create a cycle identifier.  Where the Letter changes on the cycle but resets every period.

[image]

I seem to have it with the following formula
IF(A1<>A2,1,IF(B1<>B2,C1+1,C1)).  Which will give results of 1, 2 or 3.    Then to get the numbers into letter form by using a switch SWITCH(C1,1,"A",2,"B",3,"C") in an adjacent cell. However I was curious if there is a more efficient or better way to accomplish this perhaps in all in one formula.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

### Period & Cycle

- Copy this formula to cell `C2` and copy it down.

```vb
=IF(B2<>B1,IF(A2<>A1,CHAR(65),CHAR(CODE(C1)+1)),C1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 365, you could use a spill formula like this:

```
=CHAR(B2:B15-XLOOKUP(A2:A15,A2:A15,B2:B15)+65)
```

[image]

You could argue that this is less efficient because it uses a lookup so there could be a speed hit with large amounts of data. On the other hand, it could be considered more efficient because it is a single formula and doesn't need to be pulled down.

If you were worried about the speed, you *could* set the binary search option in xlookup:

```
=CHAR(B2:B15-XLOOKUP(A2:A15,A2:A15,B2:B15,,2)+65)
```

(Column A has to be sorted ascending for this to work - I'm fairly sure that where there are duplicates this will still give the first match. However Microsoft are quoted as saying that there is only a slight benefit of using binary search [according to this and other articles](https://thesmartmethod.com/excel-xlookup-function-part-two/))

You could make the formula more dynamic:

```
=CHAR(B2:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B))-XLOOKUP(A2:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A)),A2:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A)),B2:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B)))+65)
```

Or using Let

```
=LET(Period,A2:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A)),
Cycle,B2:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B)),
CHAR(Cycle-XLOOKUP(Period,Period,Cycle)+65))
```